# Daterangepicker behaves differently with callback and apply.daterangepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

I've recently ran into a problem with the daterangepicker. I have a form and want to submit it whenever the user selects a new date range. I have used the daterangepicker callback and noticed that, even though I'm getting the correct values for the newly selected dates inside of the callback, the form is submitting the previous value that was there inside the daterange field.

Suppose I have a value of `2018-08-01 - 2018-08-07` inside the daterange field, and I have changed it to `2018-08-04 - 2018-08-06` using the below snippet

```
$('.multi-datepicker').daterangepicker({
        opens: 'left',
        timePicker: false,
        showCustomRangeLabel: true,
        locale: {
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        }
    }), () => { $('form#topFilter').submit(); };
```

but the value i'm getting server-side is the previous one which is `2018-08-01 - 2018-08-07`.

Then I have tried `apply.daterangepicker` and it seems working fine.

```
$('.multi-datepicker').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (event, picker) {
    $('form#topFilter').submit();
})
```

As I want the form to be submitted only when the value changes there, and not when just clicking the apply button without actually changing it, I prefer the callback method. does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

The **callback function** triggers when the changes have been registered in the internal properties of the plugin, but are not yet synced into the DOM.

The `apply.daterangepicker` event triggers after the DOM has been updated. This is why the form submit works in the second example.